# How could I set up e-mail for a domain on a EC2 Windows instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am wondering what are my options to set up e-mail for my domains on a EC2 Windows instance. I need SMTP and POP3. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to move this to serverfault.com since you'll get better help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. We could:

1. Run Exchange on a EC2 instance or,
2. Use Gmail Apps.

Recommended way is #2. Thank you.